# How can I search into Linkedin by PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, security, curl

I have a PHP script which opens http requests by using `CURL`: *(it also accepts header if it is needed)*

```html
   $c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
if ($post_paramtrs) {
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=bla&" . $post_paramtrs);
}
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $dirname . 'cookief.txt');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $dirname . 'cookief.txt');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
$follow_allowed = (ini_get('open_basedir') || ini_get('safe_mode')) ? false : true;
if ($follow_allowed) {
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
}
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 9);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
$data = curl_exec($c);
$status = curl_getinfo($c);
curl_close($c);
```

It works as well. Now, I want to get the result of linkedin's search. [Here](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/) is the page you can search. As you see it sends an ajax request to get the data. For example, if you want to search for `Peter`, it sends this request:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/typeahead/hits?q=blended&query=Peter
```

But when you open it manually, it fails and throws this error:

> CSRF check failed.

It means I have to pass this token with along the request:

[image]

---

**What's My question?** How can I find that token? Noted that it isn't exist in the DOM. Will it be created by JS? Anyway, do you have any clue for me?

Comment: You have this CSRF token in cookie with name `JSESSIONID`.

Comment: Did you find a workaround ? I am interested to know if you suceeded

Comment: With python, I could do it!

Comment: With python, I could do it, let me know if anyone is interested in python script for the same. I didn't try in php though!

Comment: @Satys yes interested to know how to did it

Comment: is there any way to get a new csrf token for every request from postman

Answer (score 0):

Search API isn't available for anonymous users, so you need to login and get a valid authentication cookie before executing this request.

Login and capture token from cookies: `li_at`

Finally, pass the cookie and CSRF token like this:

```
GET https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/typeahead/hits?q=blended&query=Peter 

cookie: JSESSIONID=NotImportant;li_at={GRAB_IT_FROM_COOKIE};
csrf-token: NotImportant
```

LinkedIn server will check `JSESSIONID` and `csrf-token` to be equal, so its value isn't important.

You can easily add a custom header to request with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` in curl